# Custom tool error: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: (0,0) :error 0111: Properties referred by the Dependent Role

Tags: .net, wcf, odata, .net-4.5

I have just upgraded to .net 4.5 went to update my OData Service Reference in my WCF Client Project and I Got this Custom tool error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: (0,0) :error 0111:: Properties referred by the Dependent Role Bill must be a subset of the key of the EntityType BillingEntities.Bill referred to by the Dependent Role in the referential constraint for Relationship BillingEntities.FK_Bill_Batch_BatchId.

Any ideas on how to fixes this??

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is an issue with WCF Data Services and not entity framework.  I reproduced this on my environment. I found that the EDMX CSDL namespace is different between versions.

2.0 EDMX designer xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/10/edmx"
WCF Service $metadata - xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm"

3.0 EDMX designer - xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx"
WCF Service $metadata - xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm"

As you can see the 3.0 defines a edm version significantly newer than the 2.0 but is published by WCF Data Services as a downgraded version from 2007.

My conclusion is that the System.Data.Services.dll that ships in the GAC for 4.5 has issues supporting this.  Since WCF Data Services has spun off to a NuGet as of 4.5 I would switch to this version.  I tried this on my environment and the CSDL published by the service is correct and is consumable by my service clients.

If you can't upgrade, you'll have to use the EDMX designer in 4.0 or switch these tags behind the scenes manually, which is how I originally got this working.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee720179

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to the model being built with a different version of entity framework than what is now available in .Net 4.5. This in itself is not an issue, but it could mean the entity association may not have had a foreign key property created.

What version of the framework did you upgrade from?

You may choose to delete and re-create the model from scratch (depending on the complexity), or you may re-create the model from existing database, paying particular attention to the associations.

I had something similar when I found out .Net 4.5 didn't work on Windows Server 2003 and had to downgrade to 4.0 & another time upgrading from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0. I did have to re-create the model all over again. with EF 4.4 instead of 5.0 that you get from .Net 4.5

There are more posts on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430865/target-framework-change-4-0-to-3-5-breaks-ef-model-error-111-referential-const) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/37221bb3-1f1f-4548-bf60-63d995050b05/)